# hdmi usb dongle macrosilicon 2109 rename device

Tags: hdmi, eeprom

How can i change the product name|ID of hdmi usb dongle on the HDMI end? (how the device is named as HDMI. Currently (default) is  recognized as "HDMI to USB". )

There are many similar devices based on "Macrosilicon 2109".
for example:
https://aliexpress.ru/item/4001058525465.html

(maybe from the usb connection i can change something like EEPROM)